# Waiting for an optional process operation inside bluebird promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I have a [bluebird promise](http://bluebirdjs.com/), which runs a check. If this check is true, it can continue on. However, if this check is false, it needs to [spawn](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) an asynchronous process, which it must wait to complete before continuing.

I have something like the following:

```
var foo = getPromise();

foo.spread( function (error, stdout, stdin) {
    if (error) {
        // ok, foo needs to hold on until this child exits
        var child = spawn(fixerror);
        child
            .on('error', function (e) {
                //I need to error out here
            })
            .on('close', function (e) {
                //I need to have foo continue here
            });
    } else {
        return "bar";
    }
});
```

How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Why does your `.spread()` handler take a function with an `error` as the first argument?  That does not seem very promise-like.  Usually, an error would cause the promise to reject, not resolve.

Comment: @jfriend00: Sounds like `stderrString` to me, given the other two parameter names. An external process was executed and everything went fine, but it did write something to stderr.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I convert an existing callback API to promises?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572) - if there is anything not covered there, please [edit] your question with an explanation how your attempt did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off why does your `.spread()` handler take a callback with `error` as the first argument.  That does not seem correct.  An error should cause a rejection, not a fulfillment.

But, if that was indeed the way your code works, then you just need to return a promise from within your `.spread()` handler.  That promise will then get chained to the original promise and you can then see when both are done:

```
getPromise().spread( function (error, stdout, stdin) {
    if (error) {
        // ok, foo needs to hold on until this child exits
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            var child = spawn(fixerror);
            child.on('error', function (e) {
                //I need to error out here
                reject(e);
            }).on('close', function (e) {
                // plug-in what you want to resolve with here
                resolve(...);
            });
         });
    } else {
        return "bar";
    }
}).then(function(val) {
    // value here
}, function(err) {
    // error here
});
```

But, probably, your `.spread()` handler should not have the `error` argument there and that should instead cause a rejection of the original promise:

```
getPromise().spread( function (stdout, stdin) {
    // ok, foo needs to hold on until this child exits
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var child = spawn(fixerror);
        child.on('error', function (e) {
            //I need to error out here
            reject(e);
        }).on('close', function (e) {
            // plug-in what you want to resolve with here
            resolve(...);
        });
    });
}).then(function(val) {
    // value here
}, function(err) {
    // error here
});
```

Comment: Good call on the error piece- instead of using a then, rejected the error and used a catch to manage the resolution piece.

Answer (score 1):

wrap the spawn or any other alternative route in promise function, then keep the flow as, (sample code):

```
promiseChain
  .spread((stderr, stdout, stdin) => stderr ? pSpawn(fixError) : 'bar')
  .then(...

// example for promisified spawn code: 
function pSpawn(fixError){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {        
        spawn(fixError)
          .on('error', reject)
          .on('close', resolve.bind(null, 'bar'))        
    })
}
```